# Expressions as parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using a expression as parameter for inserting data (with EF) :

```
public bool Exists(Expression<Func<V, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _dbContext.Set<V>().Any(predicate);
}

public void AddIfNotExists(V entity, Expression<Func<V, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (!Exists(predicate))
        Add(entity);
}
```

I have a method nammed Synchronize with a different expression :

```
protected void Synchronize<T>(string resource, Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    var list = _context.RestClient.Get<List<T>>(resource);

    using (var repo = new Repository<XContext, T>())
    {
        list.ForEach(x =>
        {
            repo.AddIfNotExists(x, y => predicate.Compile().Invoke(x, y));
        });

        repo.Save();
    }
}
```

I need two parameters for my method Synchronize :

```
Synchronize<ClientLivraison>("clientlivraison", (x, y) => x.IdClientJuridique == y.IdClientJuridique && x.IdClientLivraison == y.IdClientLivraison);
```

At runtime, I have this exception :

*System.NotSupportedException : 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Invoke(X.X.SynchroDb.Entity.Origine, X.X.SynchroDb.Entity.Origine)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'*

My question, how convert/pass my expression

```
Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>
```

To

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

Comment: You don't have a LINQ expression as a parameter, you just have an Expression.  It's in no way specific to LINQ.

Comment: A LINQ to EF *query* is translated to SQL. The lambdas and expressions you used aren't executed, they are converted to SQL. The error says that the lambda you provide *can't* be translated to SQL. Specifically,  `Compile().Invoke()` can't be translated to SQL. Just remove this.

Comment: If I remove Compile().Invoke(), `repo.AddIfNotExists(x, y => func(x, y));` I have the exception : _'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities'_.

Comment: Your code probably has more serious performance issues than the performance of an equality comparison. By calling `AddIfNotExists` in such a loop you are probably executing N individual commands, resulting in N round-trips to the database. That causes delays *and* excess loggin - worst case, N times slower. EF already supports attaching detached entities

Comment: @SpeedNeo then you have to any other `Invoke()` calls. These didn't appear by themselves. In any case, your code is a rather convoluted way of adding new items to a context. PS a `WHERE ` clause is generated by the `.Where()` call. You don't have any such call. Your `AddIfNotExists` tries to emulate `Where(predicate)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know how to do otherwise for inserting a collection with checking each entry existence. I would be curious to know your comments. My code is complex but I just use the repository pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to convert `Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` by replacing the first or second *parameter* using custom [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

But the easier and more natural way would be to change the `Synchronize` method argument

```
Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> predicate
```

to

```
Func<T, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicateFactory>
```

i.e. a function delegate with parameter `T`, which when invoked returns `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` based on the passed argument.

From the caller perspective, it would be a matter of changing

```
(x, y) => x.IdClientJuridique == y.IdClientJuridique && x.IdClientLivraison == y.IdClientLivraison
```

to

```
x => y => x.IdClientJuridique == y.IdClientJuridique && x.IdClientLivraison == y.IdClientLivraison
```

and the implementation would be simply replacing

```
repo.AddIfNotExists(x, y => predicate.Compile().Invoke(x, y));
```

with

```
repo.AddIfNotExists(x, predicateFactory(x));
```

Here is the whole method:

```
protected void Synchronize<T>(string resource, Func<T, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicateFactory) where T : class
{
    var list = _context.RestClient.Get<List<T>>(resource);

    using (var repo = new Repository<GmaoContext, T>())
    {
        list.ForEach(x =>
        {
            repo.AddIfNotExists(x, predicateFactory(x));
        });

        repo.Save();
    }
}
```